# Need help with integrating $\int \frac{x}{x+2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm stuck on an ongoing loop of integration by parts... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... It looks very simple so I'm suspecting I'm missing something out.

$\int \frac{x}{x+2}dx$

Comment: See my edit in your other question. I also addressed this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac x{x+2}=\frac{x+2-2}{x+2}=1-\frac2{x+2}$$

$$\int\frac{dx}{x+a}=\ln|x+a|+C$$

Comment: what did you do to go from step 2 to 3

Comment: @DanielOrtizCosta, $$\frac{x+2-2}{x+2}=\frac{x+2}{x+2}-\frac2{x+2}=\cdots$$

Comment: If you prefer, let $u=x+2$. Then $du=dx$ and $x=u-2$. So our integral is $\int \frac{u-2}{u}\,du$. But $\frac{u-2}{u}=1-\frac{2}{u}$.

Comment: I'm getting x - 2 ln(x+2)

Comment: @DanielOrtizCosta, $$\ln|x+2|$$ not $$\ln(x+2)$$

Comment: If you differentiate the anti-derivative you obtained and simplify the expression, you will find that you _do_ get your integrand back.

Answer (score 2):

Use a $u$ substitution. Let $u=x+2$. Then $du=dx$. Then you have $x=u-2$.  Plugging into the integral, $$\int \frac{u-2}{u}du=\int du - 2\int \dfrac 1u du.$$

Comment: Which is u - 2ln|u| right? then (x + 2) - 2 ln |x+2| but that doesn't seem to be correct... what am I doing wrong

Comment: Yes, you are forgetting that you have a constant $C$ at the end of your answer.  Just let a new constant, $C_1=C+2$.  Then your answer is $x-2\ln|x+2|+C_1$.  If you had a definite integral, you will still get the same answer as the other method stated above.  You can check for yourself by integrating on the interval $[1,2]$, for example